# Managing cookies in CEF

Tags: c++, cookies, chromium-embedded

I am using CEF (Chromium Embedded Framework) with Visual C++.
Is it possible to manage cookies ?

I should want to save (by cookies) user's info.
Any suggestion on how to do it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CefCookieManager is not enough? http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/(default)/CefCookieManager.html

Comment: Ok, thank You. And if I use Chromium Embedded in Delphi, how can I call  this CookieManager ?

Comment: I'm never use delphi binding, sorry. It probably must have equivalent classes.